# html video tag hide control using css webkit

Tags: html, css

Consider the video below, is there a way to hide the toolbar icon shown below in red? I looked through many posts and found out that I could use `-webkit-media` to disable some control options, but there seemed to be no answer to how to hide the part shown in red.

The example is taken from w3school: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls disablepictureinpicture controlslist="nodownload noplaybackrate">
>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

You can add `"nodownload" and "noplaybackrate"` in controlslist which will hide the download option from the video and add `disablepictureinpicture` inside the video tag which will hide the picture in picture option and by this way the three dots gets hidden: